# Independent string manipulations variations in C

Tags: c, string

I'm experiencing a very annoying problem in C :

I wrote this function to encapsulate any string with `{}` :

```
char* encapsule(char* string) {
    char* output;
    int n;

    n = strlen(string);
    output = malloc((n+3)*sizeof(char));
    output[0] = '{';
    strcat(output,string);
    output[n+1] = '}';
    output[n+2] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```

When I use this in my main function like this it works as a charm :

```
char* foo = encapsule(getTest());
printf("foo : %s\n",foo);
```

(`getTest()` gives `001` and `encapsule(getTest())` gives `{001}`)

Now when I use this in an auxiliary function like this :

```
long ligne1(FILE* tex_file, long cursor) {
    char* line;
    char* save_text;
    char* foo;

    foo = encapsule(getTest());
    printf("foo : %s\n",foo);

    save_text = copyFile(tex_file);
    rewind(tex_file);
    line = readLine(tex_file,1);
    fseek(tex_file, rightPlace(line), SEEK_SET);
    fputs(foo, tex_file);

    cursor = ftell(tex_file);
    fputs(save_text, tex_file);
    fseek(tex_file,cursor,SEEK_SET);

    return cursor;
}
```

The printf gives me : `{��}` and it writes `{à}` in the file.

I really don't understand why the behavior of this function screws up...

Thanks for your future help, I hope !

Comment: Before `strcat` you need to null terminate the string. i.e. `output[1] = 0`

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed my problem ! I didn't think the string should be considered as terminated because it seemed to work in another context. Thanks again mate !

Comment: also, `sizeof(char)` is `1`, this is the whole idea of `sizeof` to give the size of something in terms of elements of type `char`.

Answer (score 8):

Here

```
strcat(output,string);
```

`strcat` first finds the `\0` in `output`. Where is the NUL-terminator? You did not assign it. So, your code exhibits [Undefined Behavior](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Two ways to fix the problem:

1. Switch `malloc` to `calloc`:

   ```
   output = calloc( n+3 , sizeof(char));
   ```
2. Add

   ```
   output[1]='\0';
   ```

   just before the `strcat`.

Comment: Or use sprintf(output, "{%s}", string)

Comment: Yeah. That would be much better as everything is done in one line!

Answer (score 4):

The function is invalid because you are applying function
strcat to a non-zero terminated string

```
strcat(output,string);
```

A valid function can look like

```
char* encapsule( const char *string ) 
{
    char *output;
    size_t n;

    n = strlen( string );
    output = malloc( ( n + 3 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    output[0] = '{';
    output[1] = '\0';
    strcat( output, string );
    output[n+1] = '}';
    output[n+2] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```

Another approach is to use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`. For example

```
char* encapsule( const char *string ) 
{
    char *output;
    size_t n;

    n = strlen( string );
    output = malloc( ( n + 3 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    output[0] = '{';
    strcpy( output + 1, string );
    output[n+1] = '}';
    output[n+2] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```